# COPY GZIP HDFS data into vertica

Tags: database, hadoop, vertica, nosql

I want to COPY HDFS (gzipped)data into Vetica.

I am using following command. but its not working

COPY pix001 SOURCE Hdfs(url='http://hadoopnemenode.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/bq-upload/pix/m=03/d=01/03-01.txt.gz', username='xyz') GZIP DELIMITER E'\t';

Anyone know better way to do this

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: if I run above command it gives error for GZIP.                    ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "GZIP" at character 147
LINE 1: ...=03/d=01/03-01.txt.gz', username='xyz') GZIP DELIM...

Comment: Can you unzip it outside of Vertica to confirm it doesn't have an internal corruption?

Comment: I tried that that works perfectly, the dataset is huge, thats why I am trying to load it in compress form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is GZIP support just need to compile GZIP libs [Vertica Guys helped me finally :)]

here are the steps :

1. # cd /opt/vertica/sdk/examples/
2. # make
3. # vsql -f FilterFunctions.sql
4. dbadmin=> CREATE LIBRARY GZipLib AS '/opt/vertica/sdk/examples/build/GZipLib.so';
5. dbadmin=> CREATE FILTER GZip AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'GZipUnpackerFactory' LIBRARY GZipLib;

COPY abc002 SOURCE Hdfs(url='http://hadoop-namenode.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/03-01.txt.gz', username='xyz') filter GZip() DELIMITER E'\t';

Answer (score 0):

Adding to roy answer,

Steps to make(build) are given below, (#2nd step on roy answer)

```
sudo apt-get install g++ 
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev  # for gzip 
g++ -lz -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I /opt/vertica/sdk/include -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value    -fPIC -o /opt/vertica/sdk/examples/build/GZipLib.so /opt/vertica/sdk/examples/FilterFunctions/GZip.cpp /opt/vertica/sdk/include/Vertica.cpp
```

Hint: -lz flag to link the zlib library statically with GZip.so

[Vertica Documentation for compiling UDF](http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#15773.htm)

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like copying from HDFS supports GZIP?:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HDFSConnector/LoadingDataFromHDFS.htm

I don't see it in that doc, in any case.